# Which are the leading genres of the latin "genre"?

Tags: genre

According to [Music Genres](https://primesound.org/popular-music-genres/) , the latin "genre" is the third most popular genre worldwide in Youtube Music . But the latin "genre" isnt a real genre, but an amalgamation of many very different genres such as Reggaeton, latin trap, bachata, ballenato, cumbia, merengue, salsa, corridos and many others. Is there any stats anywhere which shows which are the leading genres of the latin "genre"? My guess is Reggaeton and latin trap which is what I hear the most here are 2 of them, but I dont have any source to prove it